# Request logging in Apollo GraphQL

Tags: node.js, logging, graphql, apollo-server

Environment: Node app based on Apollo GraphQL server (direct Apollo server, no express middleware)

I need to intercept requests and log log them at certain points of the processing pipelines. Here is what I have so far:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  // code removed for clarity

  context: async ({ req }) => {
// here is the first request log, preparing the context for the upcoming calls (traceability)
},
  formatError:  async (err: any) => {
// Here I would like to finish logging, but no context is available
},
```

Problems are traceability of different logs from the same end user request and logging of the successful requests.

1- How can I relate the request context within the formatError method?

2- Where should I implement the logging of the successfully executed requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aleks,

1. You can create custom error classes which can be extended from [ApolloError](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/#subclass-with-custom-error-code) or node [Error](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/errors.html) classes. By assigning context to the error object from the resolver function, you can use it from formatError method.
2. [formatResponse](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#formatresponse) method can be used here which provides requestContext as as argument.

**formatError and formatResponse methods usage:**

```
const { ApolloServer, gql, makeExecutableSchema } = require("apollo-server");

const typeDefs = gql`
  type User {
    name: String
    username: String
    statusCode: Int
  }

  type Query {
    user: User
  }
`;

const dummyUser = { username: "dummyUser", name: "Dummy user" };

const user = () => {
  // throw new Error('Test error');
  return dummyUser;
};

const resolvers = {
  Query: { user }
};

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  context: ({ req }) => ({ headers: req.headers }),
  schema,
  introspection: true,
  playground: true,
  formatResponse: (response) => {
    response.data.user.statusCode = 200;
    return response;
  },
  formatError: (error) => {
    error.message = "Error name";
    return error;
  }
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

Trying out in middleware might be an alternate approach for both(not sure about this).

Comment: Thank you Deepak. This sounds like the correct way. However I am struggling with this formatResponse method. Can you provide a working example?
I cannot declare it correctly.

Comment: @Aleks Added the sample code. Hope this helps you.